# MySQL, how would my function to evalue a number look?

Tags: mysql

I need a function in MySQL which will evaluate a status code...

In my program this is how I evaluate it. However, in SQL I'd want to select all the status code which had a specific Reason. You can see below the reasons and that more than one can be set.

```
Sub InterpretReasonCode(ByVal pintCode As Integer)

    If pintCode >= 16 Then 
     pintCode -= 16 
     mbooBlacklistedDomain = True 
    End If

    If pintCode >= 8 Then 
     pintCode -= 8 
     mbooSneakedURLChanged = True 
    End If

    If pintCode >= 4 Then 
     pintCode -= 4 
     mbooRetriedFailedToAccess = True 
    End If

    If pintCode >= 2 Then 
     pintCode -= 2 
     mbooRequestedByAuthor = True 
    End If

    If pintCode >= 1 Then 
     pintCode -= 1 
     mbooBlackListed = True 
    End If

End Sub
```

My SQL statement would look something like this

```
Select * from MyTable where Eval_Func(StatusCode,8) = true;
```

In the future I will be expanding the function to include different flags, .e.g 32, 64, 128, 256 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a function.
You can mask it directly using [bitwise operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html)

For example:

```
-- Get all BlacklistedDomain
select * 
  from tab 
 where reason_bit_mask & 16;
```

And I advice against this on anything other than really small tables, because you can't index it properly.

Comment: So what should I do instead, ideally I don't want to add a new table for statuses and creating a field for each status seems crazy.

Comment: Re. Edit... But if its going to be slow, what do I do instead?